# Escape single quote in command in alias Terminal

Tags: macos, terminal

I am working with SVN for version control, and whenever I'm ready to commit some changes, I have to stage them all with the following command:

`svn status | grep -v "^.[ \t]*\..*" | grep "^?" | awk '{print $2}' | xargs svn add`

As you can see, it's quite complicated and I therefore went looking into making an alias for this command.

When opening `~/.bash_profile`, I added the following line:

`alias svn grab='svn status | grep -v "^.[ \t]*\..*" | grep "^?" | awk '{print $2}' | xargs svn add'`

However, there are some single and double quotes in the original command, so the alias fails to be created (ok, it gets created partially, and I can't use it).

How do I escape the single quotes in the command, so the alias will work?

Comment: Try using a _ in the alias command.  Like svn_grab no space in between.  What error is it outputting?

Comment: With the alias I have tried to set up (see above) I get the following: `-bash: alias: svn: not found` and
`-bash: alias: }^[ | xargs svn add: not found`. I have changed the name of the alias, so now it only outputs the second error.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Double quotes and escaping all `"` and `$` correctly should work:

```
 alias svngrab="'svn status | grep -v \"^.[ \t]*\..*\" | grep \"^?\" | awk '{print \$2}' | xargs svn add'"
```

I also would avoid "svn grab" so maybe svngrab or svn_grab instead.

Comment: I want the alias to be "svn grab", wouldn't it have to be: `alias svn grab="'svn status | grep -v \"^.[ \t]*\..*\" | grep \"^?\" | awk '{print \$2}' | xargs svn add'"`

Comment: Yes, I have already changed the alias, because that was also outputting an error.

Comment: Ok, no more errors, until I started using it just now. It runs the alias until `print:` and then outputs `command not found`. The whole line `-bash: svn status | grep -v "^.[ \t]*\..*" | grep "^?" | awk {print: command not found`. Any idea what's going wrong?

Comment: @Rvervuurt remove the escape in front of the $

Comment: @Rvervuurt usually you have to escape $. Maybe it's counterproductive inside the curly brackets {}

Comment: I get the same error after removing the escape character. Edit: But after opening a new tab in Terminal, it seems to work.

Comment: @Rvervuurt wait: you may have forgotten a ; after $2 so correct: ... awk '{print \$2;}' ...

Comment: Well, it did stage all the edited files and a commit worked without a problem, so escaping the $ wasn't necessary. Thanks for the help :)